# Appverifier and Visual Studio for leak detection

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, winapi

I'm running Appverifier in an application. When it detects a memory leaks the logs saids

"Address of the leaked allocation. Run !heap -p -a  to get additional information about the allocation."

I guess that's when you are running in Windbg, is there any way to access the allocation stack trace from inside Visual Studio ?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. You will have to use WinDbg to track those down.

http://www.winprogger.com